# access mongoHQ db in my rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongohq

How to access MongoHQ db in my rails app, I need to get perform a search on the db and get results on my rails app.
I am using mongo db for the first time so please be more specific, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi i have done with mongoid but you can manually specify connection if you are not using mongoid,
In your mongoid.yml or wherever you are specifying connection
Your connection parameter looks like

> MONGOID_DATABASE    = "DB Name"
>
> MONGOID_HOST        = flame.mongohq.com
>
> MONGOID_PASSWORD    = password
>
> MONGOID_PORT        = 27064